# EF 6 Code First migrations warn of or prevent destructive updates

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Question: Is there a setting to be warned of inadvertent loss of data when running a migration script.

I've been using code first migrations since 4.1, but while experimenting in a test project I ran into behavior I didn't expect. Maybe I haven't kept up on newer features.

Say I have a simple model:

```
    public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

and context:

```
    public class CustContext : DbContext
{
    public CustContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

I've already enabled migrations, created the initial migration, updated the database as follows, then **populated the table with data.**

```
enable-migrations
add-migration initial
update-database
```

Then I changed the name of Address to HomeAddress. This is the migration script:

```
add-migration HomeAddress

    public partial class HomeAddress : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Customers", "HomeAddress", c => c.String());
        DropColumn("dbo.Customers", "Address");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Customers", "Address", c => c.String());
        DropColumn("dbo.Customers", "HomeAddress");
    }
}
```

This is the Configuration script:

```
    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CodeFirstMigrations.Model1.CustContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(CodeFirstMigrations.Model1.CustContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

When I ran the update-database command, I fully expected to get an error along the lines of "could not complete the migration because it would result in data loss..." I actually see that error a lot working on my own project.

But instead it happily dropped the (populated) Address column, and created a new column HomeAddress.

I figured there must be a configuration setting to control that behavior, but all I could find was `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed` which apparently only applies to Automatic migrations.

Have I overlooked something?

Comment: AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed is doing exactly what it means, I think I am a bit confused.

Comment: AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = False changes nothing in the scenario I described, because these are not Automatic migrations

Comment: What is your migration settings?

Comment: Sorry J.W., I'm not sure what 'migration settings' you're referring to? I did update my question with the configuration class and some more migration steps specifics.

Comment: If I use automatic migrations (which I never do) I will get a warning about data loss. If I use explicit migrations I don't get a warning about data loss. I thought for sure it did in the past, but perhaps I'm mistaken.
But that's my objective, to be alerted that data loss will occur for explicit migrations.

Comment: Here is the list of different type of DBInitialzer, which one do you use? http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I'm not specifying one explicitly which means I get the default, CreateDatabaseIfNotExists. But I don't think that has any bearing on this issue. I'll add my context definition to the original post.

Comment: This has been raised as an issue already but rejected as "by design". [See the bug](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/556).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been raised as an issue already but rejected as "by design".

> Decided this is by design - we only warn for automatic migrations with data loss.

See the bug [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/556).

Comment: this is pretty unsatisfying, but I suppose it has to count as a correct answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
public partial class HomeAddress : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Customers", "HomeAddress", c => c.String());
        Sql("UPDATE "dbo.Customers" SET HomeAddress = Address");
        DropColumn("dbo.Customers", "Address");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Customers", "Address", c => c.String());
        DropColumn("dbo.Customers", "HomeAddress");
    }
}
```

Then you save your data.